# Zend - Doctrine delete cascade

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine, cascading-deletes

I am hoping someone can help with this. Please

I have two tables in a one-to-may relationship: A and B. I am trying to use a delete cascade as advised in the doctrine model.

Basically in my controller id do this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->delete('Tcc_Model_A i')
        ->whereIn('i.A_ID', $input->ids);
  $result = $q->execute();
```

I my model I have this:

```
 $this->hasMany('Tcc_Model_B', array(
            'local' => 'A_ID',
            'foreign' => 'B_ID',
            'cascade' => 'delete'
                )
            );
```

Even though the primary key in the Tcc_Model_A is correctly deleted, the foreign keys (B_IDs) are not. Does someone know what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any even little help. F.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to enforce cascading operations in application code.  These operations cannot be performed atomically by application code.

Implement cascading operations by declaring a `FOREIGN KEY...ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint in your database.  They must be handled by the RDBMS.

---

Re your comment:

Foreign keys can provide support for cascading updates and deletes, and they function atomically so the changes to both parent and dependent table occur together.

```
ALTER TABLE Tcc_Model_B ADD FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) 
  REFERENCES Tcc_Model_A(A_ID)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Thank you for your input Bill. Can I just ask you to be more specific? I am not sure who to implement the way you advise. Considere that I ma using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Doctrine 2, there is support for **ON DELETE CASCADE** by configuring the **@JoinColumn** with the **onDelete="cascade"** option.

Comment: Thank you Kurt. I sort it out using Mysql cascade.